# Http post request using fopen

Tags: php, http-post

In the first file - the file I execute I have the following content:

```
<?php   
$name = "Julia";
$article = "I like papers";
$url = "http://domain.com/process.php";
$param = array('http' => array(
          'method' => 'POST',
          'content' => $article

        ));

$mad = @stream_context_create($param);
$fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $mad);
$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
echo $response;
?>
```

in the second file http://domain.com/process.php I have this:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$article = $_POST["content"];
$article = $_POST["article"];

echo $article;
echo $name;
echo "Hello there</br>:\n";

?>
```

The output that I get is just:

```
 "Hello there"
```

So what is wrong, how do I pass the values $article and $name via the request and how to I extract them in the file process.php?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got it wrong at the content part, use `http_build_query()` to build the POST query.

```
$param = array( 'http' => array('method' => 'POST',
                                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                                'content' => http_build_query($data)
                                ));
```

And your post parameters should be like below, where the input name as key

```
$data['name'] = 'Julia';
$data['article'] = 'I like papers';
```

Personally, I will use curl.

Comment: Works thanks very much. Still I was not able to archive multithreading - but that is another question.

Comment: You mean simultaneous request? There is a thing called `curl_multi_init`. You can look that up

Comment: I tried this one as well, it works everywhere except on the server where I need it to work :)  This should work as well because fopen should be asynhronius .. I just call 2 pages.

Comment: A good cURL PHP example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-and-http-post-example